# Best way to define functions within react functional components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, react-hooks

There is a lot of guidance online about defining functions within React.Component objects, but I am having trouble finding best practices for functions within Functional Components.  For instance, what are the implications of myFC_1 vs myMC_2 in the typescript code below.

```
interface Props { name: string};

export const myFC_1: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props:Props) {
    function helloWorld(): string {
        return "Hello " + props.name;
    }
    return <div> { helloWorld() }</div>
}

export const myFC_2: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props:Props) {
    const helloWorld =():string =>  {
        return "Hello " + props.name;
    } 
    return <div> { helloWorld() }</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just be consistent every time you are doing this.. In functional component it doesn't really matter which approach u use. Fat arrow can be maybe a bit slower because of automatic binding which is useless in functional component, but I am literally just guessing without any benchmark :).

Class component is different thing.. When you are defining function inside render use fat arrow, so you don't have to think about context binding. So the main thing here is to just make deal with your team what you will use and then follow this rule.

Comment: The performance may differ between engines but it is normally the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's no best way, this is a matter of preference.

Function declaration can benefit from hoisting if necessary:

```
export const myFC_1: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props:Props) {
    return <div> { helloWorld() }</div>

    function helloWorld() {
        return "Hello " + props.name;
    }
}
```

And arrow function can be a one-liner:

```
export const myFC_2: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props:Props) {
    const helloWorld =() => "Hello " + props.name;

    return <div> { helloWorld() }</div>
}
```

`string` type is optional because it is inferred.